# Invalid function or invalid domain

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Let $ f : A \rightarrow B $
What happens if  $\exists\ a\in A $ which doesn't map to any element in B ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That the function is not defined on $a$, and thus it's not defined on $A$.

Answer (score 1):

Such a thing should never happen. If $f$ is a function with domain $A$ and condomain $B$ then for every element $a$ of $A$, $f(a)$ must be a unique element of $B$.